# Access to local webserver with XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I'm using local server where XAMPP is running on. This local server is in the same network as my own computer. Now I want to access different site's running on that server. I had the following in mind.

My local server IP is `10.0.0.2`. In my own hosts file I added the following.

```
10.0.0.2 www.domain.nl
```

Now when I enter `www.domain.nl` in my browser, I will be redirected to the server's localhost.

At the server, I added a VirtualHost to the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/domain
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

So now I will be redirected to the website running in the folder `domain`.

**The problem**

The problem now is, I also have a other website running on the local server. This one is on 
the local server located in `c:/xampp/htdocs/anotherdomain`.

Adding another virtualhost does now only work on the local server itself, but not remote, because from remote I will always have the `ServerName` `localhost`.

How will I set this up? Hope you all understand my problem and someone knows how to get this working.

Comment: I think your problem might be that your computer will check for vitualhost first but other people's are going to check the internet and not consult your server. It's local to your computer. If you want to get other people to connect to you then use your computer's full external IP, turn off your firewall, and have people type in that IP into their browser and naturally make sure your on the same WIFI.

Comment: @JustGage, no that's not the issue. In fact the local server (10.0.0.2) should functions as a webserver with several website's running on in. Do I need something like DNS..?